# iOS Charts, Remove extra space created by xAxis Labels at bottom

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, ios-charts

I have a vertical normal looking bar chart created with iOS Charts. My issue is that for some reason whenever I run the program, the chart does not fill up the view it is in from top to bottom. **I am specifically trying to fix the fact that there is a small space between the bottom of a bar and the bottom of the UIView. How can I remove this space so the bottom of the bar aligns perfectly with the bottom of the UIView? (Need No gap)**

Here is my code:

```
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .top 
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    barChartView.data?.setDrawValues(false)
    barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12.0)!
    barChartView.legend.enabled = false
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:xValues)
    barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOption: .easeInQuint)
    barChartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    barChartView.barData?.barWidth = 0.65
```

Here is a pic of the issue...I need to get rid of that gap between the bottom of the bar and the red space. The UIView that the graph is in (Not the same as the red view) reaches down to the border of the red view.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve my problem by adjusting the bottom constraint programmatically based on the size of the phone's display.

I added this code into viewWillAppear and I will continue to do this for the rest of the iPhone sizes and not just the Xs:

```
if UIScreen.main.bounds.height == 896{
        print("Xs Max")
        bottomConstraintGraph.constant = -31.5 // bottomConstraintGraph is the constraint connected from the bottom of the graph's view to the superview and changed here through an outlet connection.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 barChartView.minOffset = 0.0
```

If this is not worked, add this too.

```
barChartView.extraBottomOffset = -10
```

Comment: Hmmm...Didn't work and didn't change anything with the graph

Comment: Could you attach an image of your problem?

Comment: I just added a pic

Answer (score 0):

I can't discover special options in `BarChartView` to resolve your problem. But I can suggest another way. You can embed your `barChartView` into another view and set a vertical space constraint from between bottom of your `barChartView` to bottom a superview with a negative value, also set `clipToBounds = true` for the superview. So the bottom of `barChartView` will be below the bottom of superview and will be cut.

[image: views hierarchy]

View after embedding (yellow background - superview, white - barChartView).

[image: view after embedding]

View after bottom constraint was set to -14.

[image: view after bottom constraint was set]

Comment: Sounds interesting...I'll try this later when I have some time.

Comment: When I add a " - 14" to my bottom constraint in the same area as you did in the top picture, for some reason there is no effect when I run it. Is there something else I need to do? The constraint line doesn't appear to be changed even if I add the - 14...

Comment: Wait nvm I just got it to change...now it looks fine on an iPhone 7 plus, but when I view it on a full screen display in which the red view holding the view that contains the graph being stretched to fit the proportions of the new screen, the bar appears off once again. Maybe there's a way to set a constraint only for full screen displays? Btw -22 worked

Comment: Maybe a way to calculate the size of the gap for each screen? Anyway I think adjusting the constraint for full screen displays is the best solution...I just need some help now on how to do that. thanks